How can I resolve the "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'"error when saving an image in C# WinForm?
When saving the image in C# WinForm, I encountered the following error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

Here is the updated code with the necessary modifications:
string imagePath = Path.Combine(imagesFolder, $"SavedImage_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.png");
image.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

i try to change the why of saving like using Bitmap but dont work

How is the image loaded? What is done with the image? That all matters to determine its current state at the moment you try to save it.

Ensure image is a valid Image object and not disposed before saving.
Check for sufficient disk space on the drive where you're saving the image.
Ensure the application has write permissions to the folder.
You can add this checkings:

    if (image == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image), "The image cannot be null.");
            }

     if (!Directory.Exists(imagesFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesFolder);
            }

Or you can add try-catch if you do not want see exactly this error.
